# gem5 build fails with " Embedded python library 3.6 or newer required, found 2.7.17."

Tags: python, gem5

I cannot build gem5, when I build gem5,the terminal shows " Embedded python library 3.6 or newer required, found 2.7.17.".However,when I check my python version, I find my python version is 3.6.

```
python --version

Python 3.6.7
```

Answer (score 3):

The gem5 build environment does not use your user environment. This means your custom values for PATH and other environment variables won't be set. My intuition is your Python 3 installation is pointed to by one of your custom values. In the absence of these, gem5 uses the Python system installation, which is Python 2 in your case.

A section and a fix for your case is in the official documentation: [Python in a non-default location](https://www.gem5.org/documentation/learning_gem5/part1/building/#python-in-a-non-default-location). Essentially you should run SCons through your `python3` executable:

```
python3 `which scons` build/X86/gem5.opt
```

If your `python3-config` executable is not available in a system path, you should also pass it through the PYTHON_CONFIG build variable:

```
python3 `which scons` PYTHON_CONFIG=python3-config build/X86/gem5.opt
```

Comment: I tried this but I couldn't get it to change the embedded python version. I scanned the source code and couldn't find where the printouts come from.

Comment: @NickFelker I've edited my answer to refer to the officially documented fix. The error is printed from the top level `SConstruct` file, specifically [in this line](https://gem5.googlesource.com/public/gem5/+/refs/tags/v22.1.0.0/SConstruct#354) for version v22.1.0.0.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below commands. It worked for me.

```sh
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install python-dev scons m4 build-essential g++ swig

sudo apt install python3-pip

pip3 install scons

scons build/X86/gem5.opt -j8
```

Comment: `python-dev` does not work for me, but `python3-dev` does work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 20.04, or related Linux distributions, you may install all these dependencies using the command below:

```
sudo apt install build-essential git m4 scons zlib1g zlib1g-dev \
    libprotobuf-dev protobuf-compiler libprotoc-dev libgoogle-perftools-dev \
    python3-dev python-is-python3 libboost-all-dev pkg-config
```